# jConfirm box not appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jconfirm

I have a javascript function that gets called when a form submission button is clicked, to do some validation. If everything is okay a plain javascript confirm window is executed to ensure the users wants to submit the form. However, I want to use jConfirm to tailor the title to my needs instead of "So and so page says: ".

Here's what I have:

```
function validate(form) {
  var fieldcheck = true;

  if(!checkUSPhone (form.elements["phonenumber"],true))
    fieldcheck = false;
  if(!checkEmail (form.elements["emailaddress"],true))
    fieldcheck = false;

  if(fieldcheck) {
    jConfirm(("Submit Changes"), 'Are you sure?', function(fieldcheck) {
        if(fieldcheck)
        {
            alert("True");
            fieldcheck = true;
        }
        else
        {
            alert("False");
            fieldcheck = false;
        }
    });
  }

  return fieldcheck;
}
```

I am using jQuery v1.7.2 and have jquery.alert.js v1.0.3 and the jquery.alert.css file linked to the page.

However, when the user submits the form no box appears and the page submits. I've looked at other examples on here and my syntax matches what's been said to be correct.

What am I missing?

Comment: You can not return from an asynchronous method!

Comment: I had added it in for some misguided reason. The jConfirm box doesn't appear, regardless.

Comment: BECAUSE the form submits...you can not cancel the form submission with a dialog like this. Change the `return fieldcheck;` to `return false` and watch the "alert" appear.

Comment: I see... I'm using the wrong tool for the job then. Is there something else I could use?

Comment: No, you need to change how it works...You need to call submit from the dialog.

Comment: So, right now the validate function is bound to the form's submit button via an on click event, like so: <input type="submit" class="navbutton" onclick="return validate(this.form)" value="Save">. So I should make a hidden submit button and add a new, regular button with the onclick event? And should the validation pass, have the javascript submit the form with the hidden submit button?

Answer (score 0):

Like epascarello is suggesting, you only need to make a few changes to your code:

```
function validate(form) {
  var fieldcheck = true;

  if(!checkUSPhone (form.elements["phonenumber"],true))
    fieldcheck = false;
  if(!checkEmail (form.elements["emailaddress"],true))
    fieldcheck = false;

  if(fieldcheck) {
    jConfirm(("Submit Changes"), 'Are you sure?', function(fieldcheck) {
        if(fieldcheck)
        {
            alert("True");
            form.submit();// The user has confirmed, we proceed to submit.
        }
        else
        {
            alert("False");
            fieldcheck = false;
        }
    });
  }

  return false;// Prevent submit. We'll submit the form after the user has confirmed through jConfirm.
}
```